# Why is the file upload ignoreing the language setting?

Tags: html, internationalization

I have an English and German site, where the user can switch from English to German. When the user switches the site, the content is translated, the language information is set (`lang="en", lang="de"`) but file upload (`<input type="file">`) is in German. Is there a way to translate it without customizing the file upload?

Example (egnlish):

```
<html lang="en"  xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Internationalisation test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="test">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example (german):

```
<html lang="de"  xml:lang="de">
<head>
    <title>Internationalisation test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="file" name="test">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file input button's caption is not in German per se, but in web browser's language. Should you use a web browser with different language pack or install it on different OS language, the language would be different.

Is there any way to fix this?
Yes and no.

I'll start with no. If you want to stick to standard HTML control `<input type="file">` there is no way to translate the caption.

What you can do though, is to replace the control with non-standard one (usually people tend to use flash-based file upload controls), or... The other way is to actually hide the control (setting z-axis) and put your own text box and a button over it.
That's basically it.